# Which version of the App Center is latest? Either Codova based or IBM MobileFirst?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

IBM provides two ways to generate the App Center Mobile Client. Either using their own MobileFirst Project or Cordova Project.. Among them which is the latest version? What is the latest version of .apk that IBM provides? Whether the .apk is built using native android?

(IBMApplicationCenter.apk file is in the directory ApplicationCenter/installer)

Comment: I believe you are using 8.0 ?

Comment: Yes I am using IBM MobileFirst 8.0. Using the .apk file IBM provides, UI seems to be too old. Whether there is anyway to upgrade that .apk file?

Answer (score 1):

Your Question : IBM provides two ways to generate the App Center Mobile Client. Either using their own MobileFirst Project or Cordova Project

Answer: Pure Cordova based is a new one. So, with this there is no dependency on Worklight studio. You can build the project using android studio.

Comment: Can you please provide us any reference doc or link to justify the case? It will be helpful for us.

Comment: I cannot find the pure corodva based app center codebase in the server. Is there any steps that have been missed during server installation? Please help me to find the cordova based code-base..

Comment: have latest fixes installed on the V8.0 and you should get it.